# How to install extensions on React Native installed with Cocoapods?

Tags: ios, npm, cocoapods, react-native

I just installed React Native following the instructions here: 
http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/embedded-app-ios.html#content

However, I don't know how to install third-party extensions like [react-native-icons](https://github.com/corymsmith/react-native-icons). What I have tried so far is to `npm install react-native-icons` in  ReactComponent directory. But when I run the app, it shows the error saying that **react-native-icons cannot require react-native**, which is understandable since react-native is NOT in `node_modules`. So what is the correct way to install extensions when React Native is installed with Cocoapods? Any hint is appreciated!

Comment: I am running into the same problem.  Did you figure anything out?

Comment: No...I gave react native up and turned to a real native app.

Comment: Anyone figure this one out yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the extension you want to use does not have one, you will need to create a Podspec for it. You can copy over most of the info from the extension's `package.json` file.

An example podspec, taken from https://github.com/fraserxu/react-native-couchbase-lite/blob/master/ReactNativeCouchbaseLite.podspec

```
# To learn more about a Podspec see http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html
#

Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = "ReactNativeCouchbaseLite"
  s.version          = "0.2.2"
  s.summary          = "couchbase lite binding for react-native"
  s.license          = 'MIT'
  s.platform     = :ios, '7.0'
  s.requires_arc = true
  s.authors      = "Fraser Xu <xvfeng123@gmail.com>"
  s.homepage     = "https://github.com/fraserxu/react-native-couchbase-lite.git"
  s.source       = { :git => 'https://github.com/fraserxu/react-native-couchbase-lite.git' }
  s.source_files = 'ios/**/*.{h,m}'
  s.dependency 'couchbase-lite-ios'
  s.dependency 'couchbase-lite-ios/Listener'
end
```

Once you've confirmed its working, go ahead and send the author a pull request with the Podspec file like I did :)